# Not able to get Current Item

Tags: sitecore

From the Sitecore Tree I had one Page Item(say A) on which one rendering is using data source(say "Aa"). And Item "Aa" has also presentation with having rendering is pointing to one wffm form.

`Structure is like:
Content
->A (has one rendering item on presentation having data source is pointing to 'Aa')
->Aa (has one rendering item on presentation having data source is pointing to wffm)`

Now while trying to debug "A" item and checking `Sitecore.Context.Item` then getting current Item as "Aa" instead of "A".

Can anyone please help to get current Item as A, while debugging A item

Comment: I tried replicating your issue, which I could not able to. Which version of Sitecore are you on? Where r u getting Aa value as context.Item, I mean to ask in a view rendering or controller rendering?

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri i was trying to create custom datatype with wffm on which if we are rendering the page then i need current page item, So that i can perform the action.

And i am using sitecore 8.1 and working on wffm module for custom datatype


`A is actual page where form is getting displayed 
 
Aa is the page which is currently using as data source on item A.

and there is one form which is using as data source to the rendering of the item Aa.`